# A-Frame: mouseenter/mouseleave for parent entity only

Tags: javascript, aframe

I have a 'target-circle' component which is a simple circle with a ring outside it. I'm trying to get mouseenter and mouseleave events for the *entire* component, but the event listeners attached to the *parent* element fire for the child entities and only when the raycaster hits something.

I've attempted various ways to put invisible hit-testing circles/rings to try and alleviate the problem, but they all have the core issue that multiple enter/leave events are fired for child entities.

Is it feasible/what is the best way to only get events for entering/leaving the entire parent entity?

Demo: https://output.jsbin.com/tucuxas/quiet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.6.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      AFRAME.registerComponent('target-circle', {
        schema: {
          position: {type: 'vec3', default: {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0}}
        },

        init: function() {
          var el = this.el;

          el.setAttribute('position', this.data.position);
          el.object3D.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));

          var outerRing = document.createElement('a-entity');
          outerRing.setAttribute('class', 'outerRing');
          outerRing.setAttribute('material', {
            color: 'black'
          });
          outerRing.setAttribute('geometry', {
            primitive: 'ring',
            radiusInner: '1.2',
            radiusOuter: '1.4'
          });

          var innerCircle = document.createElement('a-entity');
          innerCircle.setAttribute('class', 'innerCircle');
          innerCircle.setAttribute('material', {
            color: 'black'
          });
          innerCircle.setAttribute('geometry', {
            primitive: 'circle',
            radius: '0.3'
          });
          
          el.appendChild(outerRing);
          el.appendChild(innerCircle);
          
          el.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
            console.log('mouseenter');
          });
          
          el.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
            console.log('mouseleave');
          });
        }
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene>
      <a-entity target-circle='position: 0 3 -10'></a-entity>
      <a-entity camera look-controls>
        <a-entity id="cursor" cursor="fuse: false;" material="color: black; shader: flat;"
                  position="0 0 -1"
                  geometry="primitive: ring; radiusInner: 0.001; radiusOuter: .005;  "></a-entity>
      </a-entity>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want the mouseenter/leave to work inside the ring on the blank area ?

Comment: I want it to work on the entire component, so that you get one mouseenter as your cursor passes into the outer black ring. Then no events as you pass into the blank area or the inner circle, and finally a mouseleave if you exit the outer black ring to the rest of the scene. Thanks! :)

Comment: Use pointer-events: none; CSS property on child elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although SamB's anwser is correct in this case, I'm not sure if blocking the pointer-events in css will work on all raycasters ( even though it should ), here is my idea of wrapping the children in a container entity, just for the raycast:

Because Your entire entity consists of a ring, and a small circle inside, the parent entity is just an empty holder for the child entities. 
The mouseleave event fires when you leave the ring, because between the ring, and the circle, there is literally nothing. If You want to fill in the space ( in 2D ), You need to either:

- Create a child entity, which will be an invisible circle with the radius of the outer ring. Invisible means `opacity = 0`, not `visible = false` ( for the visible attribute is responsible for the rendering, not visibility ), and place it in front of the other children.
- Make the parent entity a circle primitive, with the same attributes as described above.

If You want to fill it in 3D space, instead of a circle, create an invisible cylinder, paper thin, just so it could block the raycasts from all sides.
 Working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/sh1hy8ee/).

Comment: Thanks Piotr. I previously attempted both of these (which are give-or-take equivalent), and found that it still fires repeated mouseenter/mouseleave events due to pixel overlap with the transparent layer (they are at identical 3D space coordinates). See http://output.jsbin.com/nemuqut/quiet (transparent made red for example). If you move the cursor over the centre small circle you will get repeated enter/leave events fired.

Comment: Ah, got your update as I posted. Possibly dumb question, but position `0 0 0.01` is not going to work for all coordinates/angles, right? I think I will need to translate the hittest circle along a vector towards the camera to be totally correct.

Comment: @Stephen i've updated my anwser a bit, since I found out this behaviour while making a fiddle for You, I hope it will be satisfactory now :)

Comment: @Stephen 1. the circle will always be in front of the target. 2. i would place there a invisible cylinder, thick as the ring/circle, so it would cover all angles, how bout that ?

Comment: @Stephen updated, if correct, ill tidy up my anwser :)

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS classes for innerCircle and outerCircle add following property

```
pointer-events: none;
```

Comment: You god damn css ninja, this is actually great, will it ignore all raycasts/laser control stuff etc ?

Comment: Yes, it should.

Comment: @Stephen, did you give it a try?

Comment: Sorry, I may have misunderstood but http://output.jsbin.com/nemuqut 
(updated with your idea) doesn't appear to work? I still get events on the outer ring and inner circle.

Answer (score 0):

An updated solution for A-Frame 0.8.0:

- Create a transparent `a-circle` as the parent
- Add the `a-ring` as a child of the `a-circle`
- Add `raycaster="objects: a-circle (and comma-separated selectors of any other elements you need the cursor to interact with in the scene); recursive: false"` to the cursor entity in your scene

The `raycaster` component settings here will prevent your cursor from intersecting with elements in the scene other than the ones whose selectors match what's listed in the `objects` property, as well as limiting the intersections to the top-level element that matches, ignoring all descendents.

More on the `raycaster` component: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/docs/components/raycaster.md